# Guide on using different types of variables in a python class?

Tags: python, oop

I've spent some time looking for a guide on how to decide how to store data and functions in a python class.  I should point out that I am new to OOP, so answers such as:

> data attributes correspond to “instance variables”
>   in Smalltalk, and to “data members” in C++. (as seen in http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html

leave me scratching my head.  I suppose what I'm after is a primer on OOP targeted to python programmers.  I would hope that the guide/primer would also include some sort of glossary, or definitions, so after reading I would be able to speak intelligently about the different types of variables available.  I want to understand the thought processes behind deciding when to use the forms of `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` in the following code.

```
class MyClass(object):
    a = 0

    def __init__(self):
        b = 0
        self.c = 0
        self.__d = 0

    def __getd(self):
        return self.__d

    d = property(__getd, None, None, None)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a`, `b`, and `c` show different *scopes* of variables. Meaning, these variables have a different visibility and environment in which they are valid.

At first, you need to understand the difference between a class and an object. A class is a vehicle to describe some generic behavior. An object is then created based on that class. The objects "inherits" all the methods of the class and can define variables which are bound to the object. The idea is that objects encapsulate some data and the required behavior to work on that data. This is the main difference to procedural programming, where modules just define the behavior , but not the data.

`c` is now such a instance variable, meaning a variable which lives in the scope of an instance of `MyClass`. `self` is always a reference to the current object instance the current code is run under. Technically, `__d` works the same as `c` and has the same scope. The difference here is that it is a convention in Python that variables and methods starting with two underscores are to be considered private are are not to be used by code outside of the class. This is required because Python doesn't have a way to define truely *private* or *proteted* methods and variables as many other languages do.

`b` is a simple variable which is only valid inside the `__init__` method. If the execution leaves the `__init__` method, the `b` variable is going to be garbage collected and is not accessible anymore while `c` and `__d` are still valid. Note that `b` it is not prepended with `self`.

Now `a` is defined directly on the class. That makes it a so called class variable. Typically, it is used to store static data. This variable is the same on all instances of the `MyClass` class.

Note that this description is a bit simplified and omits things like metaclasses and the difference between functions and bound methods, but you get the idea...

Answer (score 2):

1. a. is for variables shared by all instances of `MyClass`
2. b. is for a variable that will exist only within the `init` function.
3. c. is for an attribute of the specific `MyClass` instance, and is part of the external interface of `MyClass` (i.e. don't be surprised if some other programmer mucks around with this variable). The disadvantage of using "c", is that it reduces your flexibility to make changes to `MyClass` (at some point, someone is probably going to rely on the fact that "c" exists and does certain things, so if you decide to reorganize  your class, you will need to be prepared to keep "c" around forever).
4. __d. is for an attribute of the specific `MyClass` instance, and is part of the internal implementation of `MyClass`; it can be assumed that only the code of `MyClass` will read/write this attribute.
5. d. Makes __d look in many ways like c. However, the advantage of using d with __d is that if, for example, d() can be computed from some other attribute it would be possible to eliminate the additional storage of __d. Also, you ensure that this is only read externally, not written externally.

Answer (score 2):

A newbie-friendly online book which is widely-recommended is [Dive into Python](http://diveintopython.net/toc/index.html)
See Chapter 5 especially.

As to your questions:

- *a* is a class variable (identical for all objects of that class.)
- *b* is a local (temporary) variable not related to the class. Assigning to it inside the *`__init__()`* method might make you think it persists after the *`__init__()`* call, but it doesn't. You might think that *b* could refer to a global (as it would in other languages), but [in Python when scope is not explicitly specified and there is no *global b* statement in effect, a variable refers to the innermost scope](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces).
- *c,d* are instance variables (each object can have different values); and their different semantics mean:
- *c* is an ordinary instance variable which can be read or written as *object.c* (the class doesn't define a getter or setter for it)
- *`__d`* is a private variable, read-only, and intended to be accessed through the getter function *getd()* ; its property line shows you it has no setter *setd()* hence cannot be changed. The double-underscore prefix `__` signifies it is internal and not intended to be accessed by anything outside the class.
- *d* is a property which allows (readonly) access to *`__d`*, but as Michael points out without needing storage for an extra variable, and it can be computed dynamically when *getd()* is called.